# Telerik Rad Chart Have extra space between legends and bars

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, telerik, radchart

I am using telerik RadChat control of bar type.
My Problem is that it have lot of space between the bar and the legends.
Does anyone have solution, have i can remove this extra space.

I tried below,
            chart.DefaultView.ChartArea.AxisY.ExtendDirection = AxisExtendDirection.Smart;

if remove extra space, but while changing the binding source again and again, the bar and the count on the bars overlaps.

Can anyone have idea, how to get rid of this??
[image]

Thanks and Regards
Raj Sharma

Comment: Does any one hava any idea about this???

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the plotarea dimensions like this give this code in .cs(code behind)

**chartname.PlotArea.Appearance.Dimensions.Margins = "50px,20px,80px,80px";**

change the simension as per you need.